# Is this alternating series convergent?

Tags: calculus

> Is the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n-1}$$ convergent ?

I tried using the alternating series test and that way it is convergent. But the first term is infinity which makes the series divergent...

Comment: $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n-1}}$ is not defined. Thus it has no sense to discuss if it is convergent or divergent.

Comment: If a series is undefined at one of it's terms, it's meaningless.

Comment: The first term is NOT infinity, because it is not a limit, it is merely a fraction.

Answer (score 2):

If your professor gave you this problem then it may be a typo.  Perhaps he means
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n-1}
$$
which is the same as
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}.
$$
This series is conditionally convergent by the AST and $p$-tests, but with the typo intact it is neither convergent nor divergent, but rather undefined.

Answer (score 0):

See Baby Rudin 3.42:

> Suppose
>
> (a) the partial sums $A_n$ of $\Sigma a_n$ form a bounded sequence;
>
> (b) $b_0\geqslant b_1\geqslant b_2\geqslant\cdots$;
>
> (c) $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$.
>
> Then $\Sigma a_nb_n$ converges.

In your case, put $a_n=(-1)^n$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n-1}$.